# how to convert http request to JSON object in javaee5

Tags: java, json, java-ee-5, http-request

I want to convert request xml to JSON string. which framework is better to use? jettison, jackson, json-org,... and also how can I do this?
Any idea?
thanks
Afsaneh

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is to go straight from XML to JSON, without any structure transformations, data changes, or inspections, then [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org) or even [the JSON in Java reference implementation at org.json](http://www.json.org/java/index.html) can get the job done rather simply.  In similar fashion, XSLT options are available, including [XSLTJSON](http://www.bramstein.com/projects/xsltjson/) and [xml2json-xslt](http://code.google.com/p/xml2json-xslt/).

If complicated interrogation and/or manipulation of the data and resulting JSON are in order, then [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome) combined with [the jackson-xml-databind extension](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonExtensionXmlDataBinding) provide for a feature-rich option that also has excellent performance.  (Performance comparisons of some JSON and XML serialization APIs are available at https://github.com/eishay/jvm-serializers/wiki.)